# How can I extract City, Region, Country from a URL? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

My Django app currently serves 7 hard-coded cities and would like to make serve all world cities saved not as one word like "Budapest" but as three levels like "New York, New York, USA".

My Google-powered search field returns results like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/search/?city=New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States
```

How can I extract the values and save them in my model.

This is my current City model:

```
class City(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="", unique=False)  # city name
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="Scotland")  # country name
    information = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default="")  # information about city
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='city_images', default=0)#city image
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False)  # city slug

    # save function
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(City, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This line from my view only adds a new city if it doesn't exist in the database already:

```
city_name = City.objects.get_or_create(slug=city_name_slug, name=city_name_slug)
```

I'd like the view to extract City, Region, Country and save them in the model and for the slug to be unique like this:

> new-york-ny-united-states

Finally, this is my View in full:

```
def city(request, city_name_slug):
    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass to the 
    # template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}

    # if the user is logged in with a profile then status = 2. 
    # else if the user is logged in without a profile then status = 1
    # else if the user is not logged in (status = 0)
    status = navbatlogic(request=request)

    # to get the profile link in the nav bar 
    # (only viewable when logged + has a profile)
    slug_of_logged_user = get_profile_slug(request=request)

    # Can we find a city name slug with the given name?
    # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
    # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
    city_name = City.objects.get_or_create(
        slug=city_name_slug, name=city_name_slug)

    # Get the users registered to this city
    user_list = User.objects.filter(
        profile__city=city_name[0]).order_by('-profile__average_rating')[:20]

    # Add the user list, city name, slug of the logged-in user, and a 
    # status variable to the context dictionary
    context_dict['users'] = user_list
    context_dict['city'] = city_name[0]
    context_dict['slug_of_logged_user'] = slug_of_logged_user
    context_dict['status'] = status

    # If p is found in the request, we are searching for people in this city
    if 'p' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET.get('p')
        try:  
            # Look for any user with the search term in their 
            # username, page slug or first and last names
            user_list = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__contains=q) | Q(profile__slug__contains=q) | 
                Q(first_name__contains=q) | Q(last_name__contains=q)
            )

            # Make sure list contains only users registered in this city
            user_list = user_list.filter(profile__city=city_name)

            # Re-add list to context dictionary
            context_dict['users'] = user_list
        except:
            pass

    # If h is found in the request, we are searching for people 
    # with a certain hobby in this city
    if 'h' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET.get('h')
        try:
            # Look for any user with hobbies similar to the search query
            user_list = User.objects.filter(
                profile__hobbies__hobby__contains=q)

            # Make sure list contains only users registered in this city
            user_list = user_list.filter(profile__city=city_name)

            # Re-add list to context dictionary
            context_dict['users'] = user_list
        except:
            pass

    # If l is found in the request, we are searching for people with 
    # a certain language in this city
    if 'l' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET.get('l')
        try:
            # Look for any user with languages similar to the search query
            user_list = User.objects.filter(
                profile__languages__language__contains=q)

            # Make sure list contains only users registered in this city
            user_list = user_list.filter(profile__city=city_name)

            # Re-add list to context dictionary
            context_dict['users'] = user_list
        except:
            pass

    return render(request, 'cityProfile.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Can't you do this by extracting the URI and parsing this by native Python tools? (split, join etc..)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) for something like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

u = urlparse('http://localhost:8000/search/?city=New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States')
q = parse_qs(u.query)
city = q['city']
```

You could then `split` the city result to get the city, state, and country parts.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete answer? I've been: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html and wasn't able to seperate City Region and Country.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to extract these components from a well-structured source of data such as the Google Geocoding Service, so you can reliably tell which part of the data maps to an administrative division.
If you take the example from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple you'll get a JSON object with the 3-tiered structure in `address_components`:

```
"address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "New York",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ]
```

But then again, be careful, not all places have 3 tiers... Try some extreme cases and see what you get (e.g. Vatican City, Antarctica, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you provided more URLs as examples. However, from the URL you have provided, I would simply write a few lines to get the desired city and country name:

```
city: New York
title: NY
country: United States
```

The codes are as follows:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8000/search/?city=New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States'
city = url.split('/?city=')[1].split('%2C')
name, title, country = [c.replace('+',' ').strip() for c in city]
```

I hope you will find it useful. Thanks.