# How can I extract City, Region, Country from URL? Django

Tags: python, django, url, parameters

My search field returns something like this:

> http://localhost:8000/search/?city=New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States

How can I extract City, Region, Country. I've been through this document: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

and this question:

[How can I extract City, Region, Country from a URL? Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570768/how-can-i-extract-city-region-country-from-a-url-django)

But not completely sure how to seperate them.

Comment: How to "separate" what? And why would you use `urlparse` when you are using Django and can simply access `request.GET`?

Comment: Where is your code? Precisely which step are you stuck at? Can you get the URL? Extract the query parameter? Decode the e.g. `%2C` in the query parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

use django request object  "domain/search/?city=vienna"

in 
**django class based views**:

```
self.request.GET['city']
```

in 
**django function based views**

```
def get_something(request):
    return HttpResponse("%s" % request.GET['city'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

python 2.7

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> u = urlparse('http://localhost:8000/search/?city=New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States')
>>> q = parse_qs(u.query)
>>> q['city']
['New York, NY, United States']
>>> q['city'][0].split(', ')
['New York', 'NY', 'United States']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply in the Django view function. The `request` object has a `request.GET` property.

```
def my_view(request):
    crc = request.GET.get(city, None)

    if crc:
        city, region, country = crc.split(',')

    # ...
```